# USB-C DFP VBUS line

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-c

I am trying to desing extension board with USB 3.1 gen 1 Type C in DFP (host) role.

To support the flipping of the connector I chose PI5USB30213A. I planned to use default voltage and current configuration - 5V 0.9 A with no PD or 1.5 A etc. PI5USB30213A just muxing high speed lines and configure CC lines.

In the [typical application circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfCEf.png) I saw that I need a "DFP mode charging circuit ". In TI's [*A primer on USB Type-C ® and USB
Power Delivery Applications and
Requirements*](https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slyy109a/slyy109a.pdf?ts=1622754069995&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) I saw that I need a 5V VBUS FET to switch on 5V rail when some device is plugged.

PI5USB30213A has ID pin with description:

> open drain output. Asserted low then CC pin detected device attachment when port is a Host, otherwise ID is hi-z.

Can I simply connect VBUS on main 5V from main board (and some capasitor around connector) or do I need a FET (can you advise some?) to commutate 5V to VBUS pins?

Answer (score 1):

By Type-C specifications, a Type-C port **should not supply** any power until CC pins signal any connection, and power roles of connected partners are identified via Rp/Rd sense mechanism.

So yes, you do need a high-side power switch to turn VBUS on, which should be controlled by this "ID" pin. Almost any P-FET can do this job, but I would strongly advise to use a dedicated high-side switch (aka "power distribution switch) with enable=LOW, something like TPS2061.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at the specifications from USB, but I did not find the sequence that the VBUS up only after connecting the cable. Can you please indicate where you found this information.

Comment: @Quarterblad, see section 4.2.2 of Type-C specifications, which says: *"These pins are for USB cable bus power as defined by the USB specifications. This source is only present when a DFP-to-UFP connection across the CC channel is present – see Section 4.5.1.2.1. Refer to Section 4.4.2 for the functional requirements for VBUS."*